# Explain what is difference between without whitespace in scanf and with whitespace in scanf?

Tags: c, unix

```
main()
{
    int d,a;
    printf("Enter the digit :");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    printf("Enter another digit :");
    scanf("%d",&a);
}
```

output:
    Enter the digit : 10
    Enter the another digit:10

```
main()
{
    int d;
    char a[10];
    printf("Enter the digit :");
    scanf("%d ",&d);
    printf("Enter another digit :");
    scanf("%s ",a);
}
```

output:

```
Enter the digit : 10
waiting for stdin
```

Can anyone explain the difference between `scanf("%d",&a)` and `scanf("%d ",&a)`?  Why does adding a space in the `scanf` statement cause it to wait of stdin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A whitespace in a scanf format string matches *any* whitespace character, not only space, even multiple times, so if you press enter, it is a part of the matched string. If you press Ctl+D it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Having a space in `scanf` means that it will expect a space. Hence it waits for you to enter the space.

Comment: This directive (a whitespace) matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input. So no, you don't have to enter a whitespace character.