# scanf getting two lines inputs with whitespace

Tags: c, scanf

please find the below code for example

```
main()
{
    int i;
    char s[100];
    printf("Enter the string \n");
    scanf(" %s ",s);
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%s\n%d\n",s,i);
}
```

The output of above code is

```
Enter the string 
hai
hai
Enter the string
hai
0
```

It supposed to accept one line input but it is accepting second line also.
If  removed the space in scanf, the output is coming correctly.

Can anyone explain?

when using the same with integer (%d) it is not happening. It is happening with string.

Comment: It asks twice because there are two `printf` of `"Enter the string"`, surely.

Comment: There are two `printf()`s asking, that is why it asks two times? (Unless I am misunderstanding). The leading space in the format specifier instructs `scanf()` to skip leading whitespace.

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704907/explain-what-is-difference-between-without-whitespace-in-scanf-and-with-whitespa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

our first scanf wait a string containing a space at the begginingbut it there is not. so it ask you agin to enter the string and in the second time is accepted because you type [enter] before entering your new string. The [enter] is treated in scanf as a white space.

Refer to this link it seems the same

[Explain what is difference between without whitespace in scanf and with whitespace in scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704907/explain-what-is-difference-between-without-whitespace-in-scanf-and-with-whitespa)

Answer (score 1):

Your first `scanf` asks for a string and will skip leading whitespaces.
Your second `scanf` asks for an ***integer***.

When you enter `"hai"` it goes in `s[]`. It would have been the same with `"       hai"`, keeping only `"hai"`.
When you enter `"jai"` it is parsed as an `int` and thus gives you zero.

There is nothing wrong with your program except the second `printf` should be

```
printf("Enter an integer\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `scanf()`'s man page:

> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see
>   isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space,
>   including none, in the input.

When you have a whitespace in the format string, it skips any amount of whitespace characters in the input. So that means you 
have to enter a non-whitespace characters so it goes on to read your string `s`.

In C/POSIX locale, a whitespace character can be:

> space, form-feed ('\f'), newline ('\n'), carriage return ('\r'),
>   horizontal tab ('\t'), and vertical tab ('\v').

Answer (score 0):

There shoult be no space in "%s"
And the reason for the sentense coming two times is that u have written two times

Answer (score -1):

try

```
main()
{
    int i;
    char s[100];
    printf("Enter the string \n");
    scanf("%c", &s);
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("%s\n%d\n",s,i);
}
```

`fgets` would make `c` get a number of characters.

Comment: `%c` is used to read a single character.

Comment: `fgets` would make it a number of characters.

Comment: use fgets right after a `scanf("%c", ...)` is not really a good practice